# Mysql full table scan of index

Tags: mysql, ajax, select, limit, full-table-scan

I have 3,090,590 rows in a message column and I am using this code to get 3000 rows at a time.

I am trying to convert my SQL to NoSQL, for this I wrote a PHP script with Ajax. Ajax requests `$page` every time by multiplying; for e.g. 3000, 9000, 12000...

```
SELECT * FROM mesajciklar order by id ASC LIMIT $page,3000
```

Somehow, even if I limit the query it always scans full the table which makes MySQL use 100% of the available CPU. I have full indexing of every column but it's still so slow.

Could you please show me a way how to optimize it?

```
mysql> | mesajciklar | CREATE TABLE `mesajciklar` (
->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
->   `sira` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
->   `mesaj` text NOT NULL,
->   `yazar` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `tarih` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `gun` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
->   `ay` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
->   `yil` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
->   `saat` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `oy` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `update2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `updater` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `updatesebep` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `statu` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `silen` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   `silsebep` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
->   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
->   KEY `sira` (`sira`),
->   KEY `yazar` (`yazar`),
->   KEY `ip` (`ip`),
->   KEY `tarih` (`tarih`),
->   KEY `gun` (`gun`),
->   KEY `ay` (`ay`),
->   KEY `yil` (`yil`),
->   KEY `saat` (`saat`),
->   KEY `oy` (`oy`),
->   KEY `update2` (`update2`),
->   KEY `statu` (`statu`),
->   KEY `silsebep` (`silsebep`),
->   KEY `gun_2` (`gun`,`ay`,`yil`),
->   FULLTEXT KEY `mesaj` (`mesaj`),
->   FULLTEXT KEY `yazar_2` (`yazar`)
-> ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1062473327 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5 |
```

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *` just select certain columns.

Comment: I also did that before i used 'select *'. still so slow maybe its normal because my table is huge.

Comment: _"I have full indexing of every column but it's still so slow."_. You **what**????? You have indexed _every_ column?

Comment: What if you just run this exact query in a MySQL Browser(no PHP).

Comment: You'll need to show your schema and index definitions.

Comment: @Ben yes. and lannister, it has to convert every row to NoSQL(MongoDB).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson okay how can i show you that, i got little knowledge of MySQL's backend

Comment: Add the complete output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mesajciklar` to your curent question, so we can help more efficiently.